# I entered this formula and my app goes blank

Tags: google-appsheet

```
Any(IFS(Sales log[Item Code/Description]=Product List[Product Description],(Select(Product List[CFN],[_THISROW].[Item Code/Description]=[Product Description])),Sales Log[Item Code/Description]=Product list[CFN],(Select(Product List[CFN],[_THISROW].[Item Code/Description]=[CFN]))))
```

I entered this formula into my column and when i ran the app the View that is related to this code appears blank.

The previous page works perfect. I enter the necessary data and I hit Next, the page opens blank!

I tried reloading and checked my formula. It appears there is no error on that part but the app keeps going blank.

PLS provide insight to my problem